# Ionic 2 Facebook Style Footer Bar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to create a facebook looking style footer bar.  Segmented Buttons which control page navigation.  I have this Layout Page:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      {{pageName}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ng-content>
</ng-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment>
      <ion-segment-button value="users">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="notifcations">
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="posts">
        <ion-icon name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

This generates a page looking like this:

[image]

I would like the footer to look more like this:

[image]

What can I do to make the footer look like the desired one?

Comment: May I ask why segments instead of just tabs?

Comment: @sebaferreras that the component I was looking for.  I assumed they would have displayed it in their documentation in the footer or by the buttons which they had neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style is tabs in ionic check  `codepen.io/anon/pen/MyvRRr`

if you need any component check this repo [Componants](https://github.com/yannbf/ionic3-components)

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect. I just need to confirm when I get to my work comp